# GridSearchCV with TimeSeriesSplit

Tags: regression, hyperparameter-tuning, gridsearchcv

I am tuning the HPs for a time dependant neural network model (heating energy consumption prediction) in a bachelor thesis.
Total amount of samples is 145.860, with minutely granularity from January to August.

I read GridSearchCV and TimeSeriesSplit would be useful.

However, tuning the HPs shouldn't be done with any test data of my model.

If I apply a GridSearchCV(cv=tscv), being tscv my TimeSeriesSplit, each combination of parameters will be trained in every split, and assessed in the respective Test part of the split. Am I correct?

If yes, the problem is that I would be using test data to tune HPs. How is the best practice recommendation to gridsearch with cross validation for times series data? (In an academic context).